# concatenar arrays anidados con Javascript concat()

Tags: javascript, array, concat

Tengo que resolver un problema utilizando la función concat() con javascript. El ejercicio está resuelto, pero no sé cómo hacerlo con concat(). Se trata de una función a la que le paso como argumento un array que contiene arrays anidados y debe devolver un nuevo array con todos los elementos de todos los arrays. Lo he solucionado de la siguiente manera:

```
function concatArraysAnidados(array) {
  
  let newArray = []

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i ++){
    for (let j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
      newArray .push(array[i][j])
    }
  }

  return newArray 
}
concatArraysAnidados([[8, 5], [a, b], ['true', 'false']]);
// La salida sería esta --> [8, 5, a, b, 'true', 'false']
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo con concat()? En todos los intentos que he hecho solo logro devolver un array incompleto porque me lo sobreescribe durante el loop...

Comment: Probablemente lo necesitas solo como un ejercicio académico con `concat` pero si quieres resolver el problema de manera óptima puede usar directamente el método [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) en el array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas el doble bucle `for`. Puedes usar un solo bucle, y el método [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat);

Por ejemplo:

```js
function concatArraysAnidados(array) {
  let output = [];
  for (let element of array) {
    output = output.concat(element);
  }
  return output;
}
const result = concatArraysAnidados([[8, 5], ['a', 'b'], ['true', 'false']]);
// La salida sería esta --> [8, 5, 'a', 'b', 'true', 'false'] 

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Si deseas usar un bucle `for` tradicional, también puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```js
function concatArraysAnidados(array) {
  let output = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    output = output.concat(array[i]);
  }
  return output;
}
const result = concatArraysAnidados([[8, 5], ['a', 'b'], ['true', 'false']]);
// La salida sería esta --> [8, 5, 'a', 'b', 'true', 'false'] 

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!! Sí, esto es lo que buscaba. Lo estaba intentando así pero estaba concatenando a output sin reasignar el valor y eso hacía que me lo sobreescribiera todo el rato...

Answer (score 0):

Concatenando arrays anidados
En el siguiente código concatena arrays anidados y demuestra retención de referencias:

```js
var num1 = [[1]];
var num2 = [2, [3]];

var nums = num1.concat(num2);

console.log(nums);
// Da como resultado: [[1], 2, [3]]

// modifica el primer elemento de num1
num1[0].push(4);

console.log(nums);
// Da como resultado: [[1, 4], 2, [3]]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```